# do csv file names need a specific pattern while being read with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, oledb, jet

I've tried using the OleDb interfaces to read a CSV file, but I noticed something weird.

```
var filePath = @"C:\set2\orders3_1.csv";
var fileDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=indexer; Integrated Security=SSPI");
OleDbConnection cxn = new OleDbConnection();
cxn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';Data Source=" + fileDirPath;
OleDbCommand cmd = cxn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select [OrderNumber] from [{0}]", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
cxn.Open();
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
bcp.DestinationTableName = "PersonTable";
bcp.WriteToServer(rdr);
rdr.Close();
cxn.Close();
```

When I put the file name as `orders3_1.csv` it reads okay. But when I modify the file name to `orders3.1.csv` the code runs into an exception saying it cannot find the file...

Is this a known issue with the JET providers?

Comment: at what line does it throw the exception?

Comment: Error thrown at the executereader call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Jet is pretty fussy about file extensions:

> Another potential issue is that, by default, you're limited (at least
>   in Access) to what file extensions you can use. Out of the box, the
>   only file extensions you can use are txt, csv, tab and asc.

-- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3853531/Working-with-external-text-files-in-MS-Access.htm

You can modify the registry to make it accept others.

Comment: Multiple periods in the filename will cause an error. You can use an API call to get the 8.3 MS-DOS name and use that. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22680288/741136

Answer (score 0):

You have to Wrap the whole filename in quotes, but because this is a literal string use \" to escape them

```
cxn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';Data Source=\"{0}\"",fileDirPath);
```

Change the above line in your code and it should work.